# Installtion of gr-ieee802-11 using Pybombs with errors

Tags: compiling, gnuradio

I want to install gr-ieee802-11 to GNURadio.

Version: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (it is a Virtual machine)

Info when I run GNURadio in terminal: 
linux; GNU C++ version 4.8.2; Boost_105400; UHD_003.005.005-0-unknown
GNU Radio Companion 3.7.2.1

installed

```
git clone git://github.com/pybombs/pybombs
cd pybombs
./pybombs install gnuradio
```

then

```
./app_store.py


    Build failed. Re-trying with reduced makewidth and higher verbosity.
    [  4%] Built target man_page_gzips
    [ 58%] Building CXX object gr-digital/swig/CMakeFiles/_digital_swig.dir/digital_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
^Cmake[2]: *** [gr-digital/swig/CMakeFiles/_digital_swig.dir/digital_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Interrupt
make[1]: *** [gr-digital/swig/CMakeFiles/_digital_swig.dir/all] Interrupt
make: *** [all] Interrupt
Build failed. See output above for error messages.
```

Comment: Please [edit] you post to give some context - especially what software you are trying to build (gnuradio?), its **version**, and what version of Ubuntu you are running. Just dumping an error message does **not** make a good question within the terms of this site: see [How do I ask a good question](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: possibly this [gnuradio bug](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/issues/683)? see also [this revision commit](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/repository/revisions/a6bf31afb3e2bb1c3bd70cdcc66d393ff6d5feb6)

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that the version of gr-ieee802-11 that you are trying to install (from git) is newer than your installed version of gnuradio-dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to install GNU Radio via [pybombs](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/pybombs/wiki). The version in the repo is usually pretty outdated.